# Does a linear operator being diagonalizable make it an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T:V \to V$ a linear transformation. If $T$ is diagonalizable, is it always the case that $T$ is an isomorphism? I think I've shown (by example) that the converse is false. I.e., there are isomorphisms that are not diagonalizable.

I've gotten some ways into the problem but am stuck at a step.

Since by assumption $T$ is diagonalizable, there exists a basis of eigenvectors {$v_1, ..., v_n$} for $V$. Then to show that $T$ is an isomorphism it would be enough to show that $T$ is injective.

So suppose $v\in V$. Then we can write $v = a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n$.

Not suppose $T(v) = 0$:

$\to T(a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n) = 0$

$\to a_1T(v_1) + ... +a_nT(v_n) = 0 $

$\to (a_1\lambda_1)v_1 + ... +(a_n\lambda_n)v_n = 0$, since the $v_i$'s are eigenvectors. The $\lambda_i$'s need not be distinct.

Now to show that $T$ is an isomorphism it would have to be the case that no $\lambda_i$ were $0$. So I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Invertibility and diagonalizability conceptually have very little to do with each other. Note in particular that diagonalizability is invariant under adding a scalar multiple of the identity (that is, $T$ is diagonalizable iff $T + \lambda I$ is diagonalizable, for any $\lambda$) but invertibility is not.

Comment: If $T$ is diagonalisable and $\ker T = \{0\}$, then $T$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Singular transformations, for instance the one given by $T(v) = 0$ for all $v$, can be diagonalizable.

For the other direction, over $\Bbb R$, rotations are isomorphisms that are not (generally) diagonalizable.

Comment: Just to remove the restriction to $\mathbb R$ in your second example: Over any field, the linear transformation with matrix $\binom{1\ 1}{0\ 1}$ is an isomorphism but is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, of course. I was thinking about isometries. Probably need to go to bed.